# 40LB TV Mounted on Drywall using 6 Plastic Anchors. WILL THIS FALL?

Tags: drywall, anchor, television, mount

The 55' tv is 38.8 lbs and I used 6 drywall anchors rated for 80lbs. I hung it 24 hours ago at a friends house, and I've been nervous since reading contradictory information online. Having only done wood studs in the past, here I encounted metal studs and didn't have the tools to get into them. IS this an ok solution?

This website ( https://www.todayshomeowner.com/how-to-hang-anything-on-anything ) Makes me feel that it should be ok, but many ppl on reddit from the plamsa tv days have horror stories.

Comment: is it flat to the wall or a swivel mount?

Comment: Flat, no spacers.

Comment: 6X80 = 480lbs. 480 > 38.8. you should be fine, 12X over, right?

Comment: the concern is if someone pulls outward on it, as happens when trying to hook up a new cable, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll be fine. The TV won't fall off the wall unless the drywall itself fails (i.e. water damage or earthquake) or someone hangs off of it.